# Question about audio

Tags: discussion

I came out with [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17764/home-recording-preamp-or-dynamic-mic). It came to the chat, and I asked, if this question belongs to [Sound Design SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) or if it is allowed here.

Then @DrMayhem said:

> I don't think that question would work on SD. It isn't about sound
>   design. Here, I don't really think it works that well either

The Audio & Video Production SE became [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) right?

But the Sound Design SE don't clarify their [on-topic question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Then, I go down to the search, find [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16603/how-many-inputs-do-i-need-to-record-drums) and [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/external-soundcard-for-recording-making-music) question, it is allowed there, but when I check the [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question (thanks to @Meaningful). It says:

> and it is not about...
>
> - identifying a song, genre, instrument, etc.
> - shopping, product or music search, or buying/selling recommendations
> - **audio production techniques and equipment**
> - listening recommendations or recommendations of pieces to play
> - requesting a list of resources
> - legal issues

So, do question like that on-topic or allowed here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you're recording music, or sound for use in music, or it's applicable to recording music, then such a question is definitely on-topic here.  We used to refer people to Audio and later AVP sometimes in case they could get better expert answers, but obviously we can't do that anymore.

Comment: Makes sense. But what is the "audio production techniques and equipment" intended to discourage then?

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername I think that just need to be updated.  Even originally it was a poor way to distinguish us from the other site.  I've removed it :)